# Merge two PSCustomObject tables into a single one with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, merge, pscustomobject

I want to use PowerShell to merge two tables into one.

```
#Sample table
$CarList1 = @()
$CarList2 = @()

$CarList1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Brand"           = "Audi";
    "Model"           = "A8";
    "Color"           = "Red";
    "ManufactureDate" = "2000.11.01"
}

$CarList2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Brand"           = "Audi";
    "Model"           = "A4";
    "Color"           = "Green";
    "ManufactureDate" = "1998.11.01"
}
```

I want to transfer the data of $CarList2 into $CarList1

In the end I expect to have all the data in one table.

```
Brand Model Color ManufactureDate
----- ----- ----- ---------------
Audi  A8    Red   2000.11.01
Audi  A4    Green 1998.11.01
```

I have tried various things...

```
foreach ($property in $CarList2.psobject.Properties) {
    foreach ($array in $CarList2.$($property.Name)) {
        $CarList1.$($property.Name) += $array
    }
}
```

```
$CarList1 += $CarList2

...
```

I hope you could help me, I can't get it to work.

Comment: `$CarList1 = @($CarList1; $CarList2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `$CarList1 += $CarList2`

This only works if `$CarList1` *is already an array*, which is *not* the case here, because, even though you tried to initialize it as an array with `$CarList1 = @()`, that initialization had no effect given that the subsequent `$CarList1 = [PSCustomObject]@{ ... }` assignment *replaced* the value with a *single* object.

Without touching your other code, the simplest solution is to use a *type constraint* on your compound assignment, which implicitly converts `$CarList1` to an array, if needed, and additionally ensures that any future values that get assigned are converted to an `[array]` (`[object[]]`) too, if necessary:

```bash
# OK: Array concatenation, thanks to the [array] type constraint.
[array] $CarList1 += $CarList2
```

Note that in order for the [`+` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators) to perform *array concatenation*, it is sufficient for the *LHS* to be an array; if the RHS isn't, it is appended as *single* element to the output array; if it is, its elements are appended one by one.

---

It follows from the above that if you had *initialized* (at least) `$CarList1` with such a type constraint, `$CarList1 += $CarList2` would have worked as-is:

```bash
# Initialize the variables as empty arrays and *type-constrain* them as arrays.
[array] $CarList1 = @()
[array] $CarList2 = @()

# Now, even assigning a *single* object causes an *array* to
# be stored, with on-demand conversion.
$CarList1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Brand"           = "Audi";
    "Model"           = "A8";
    "Color"           = "Red";
    "ManufactureDate" = "2000.11.01"
}

# Ditto
$CarList2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Brand"           = "Audi";
    "Model"           = "A4";
    "Color"           = "Green";
    "ManufactureDate" = "1998.11.01"
}

# Since (at least) $CarList1 now is an array, array concatenation
# now succeeds.
$CarList1 += $CarList2
```

Of course, in this example you could make do without the separate initialization statements, and just do:

- `[array] $CarList1 = [pscustomobject] @{ ... }`, ...
- or, if type-constraining isn't needed, you can use [`@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to ensure that your single object becomes an array:

  `$CarList1 = @([pscustomobject] @{ ... })`

Comment: Thanks for the renewed help and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

mklement0's answer is good, but I'd also like to raise awareness of PowerShell's array operator: `@( ... )`. Anything you put inside is treated as an array.

```
$CarList1 = @($CarList1) + $CarList2
```

In this case, rename your variables to $Car1 and $Car2 for the sake of sanity ;-)

`Write-Output` is also a good one to be aware of:

```
$CarList = $Car1, $Car2 | Write-Output
```